# Docker Swarm - don't restart service on entrypoint success

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

When trying to deploy my app on Docker swarm I have two services: NGINX to serve static files and app to compile some static files. To run static files compilation I'm using entrypoint in Compose file.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:80/lib/tether/examples/viewport/index.html || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - /www:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - client

  client:
    image: my-client-image:latest
    restart: "no"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    volumes:
      - /www:/app/www
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp compilescss
```

I tried adding `restart: "no"` in my service, but service is restarted on entrypoint completion anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker 23.0.0 is now out. As such you have two options:

- stack files now support swarm jobs. Swarm understands that these run to completion. i.e. `mode: replicated-job`.
- [Docker Compose V3 Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) makes it clear that "restart:" applies to compose and "deploy.restart_policy.condition: on-failure" is the equivalent swarm statement.

Comment: I'm on Docker 20.10 so I have added "deploy.restart_policy.condition: on-failure" but now I'm left with stopped containers with status completed, is there any way to automatically remove them on job completion?

Comment: dockers local and json log drivers store container logs in the container folder. Deleting the container removes any ability to get at stop codes, logs etc, so they are kept. You can run a periodic "docker system prune" on all nodes to keep the cruft down.